# The comfort which one hath of her husband

Tags: single-word-requests

According to [an article published on quizlet.com](http://quizlet.com/1189239/the-most-difficult-and-unbelievable-word-of-the-oed-flash-cards/), titled 'The most difficult and unbelievable word of the OED' (which I dont have access to), *levament* means "The comfort which one hath of his wife".

So I wonder if there is a similar word that means "The comfort which one hath of her husband"?

Answer (score 5):

The OED entry is basically

> **† levament,** *n.*
>
> Etymology:  < Latin *levāmentum,* < *levāre* to lighten.
> *Obs. rare*<sup>—0</sup>.
> 1623   H. Cockeram *Eng. Dict.,*   Leuament, the comfort which one hath of his wife.

And no; there is no different word for the comfort a husband gives. It is the "unbearable lightness of being" which comes from being in love, and that can be felt by either sex.

The apparent gender-specificity of the definition is a product of its time. Even the word *comfort* has shifted in meaning in the last four hundred years.

Answer (score 1):

I found something similar in the link; it is:

> Maritality (n.) Excessive or undue affection on the part of a wife for her husband (see also: levament).

I'll look some more, though. Having searched for it through Oxford's *Historical Thesaurus*, I can't find anything else. Sorry.